# Creating a List of a Specific Type of Commercial Instrument Available in the Market

Tags: google-scholar, web-of-science

I'm interested in learning about all available commercial PEPT (Positron Emission Particle Tracking) scanners in the market. Is there an easier way to find this information? I've tried using "Web of Science" and "Google Scholar," but going through papers, downloading them, and searching for model numbers is quite tedious. Additionally, since I haven't worked with PEPT before, I don't know the names of major manufacturing companies. Any suggestions for a more straightforward approach to getting this information would be appreciated.

Comment: Why would one search for commercial providers of specific equipment using Web of Science or Google Scholar?

Comment: Because PEPT is used in lot of research works.

Comment: For example, if you do literature survey on PET scanners, you can easily make a long list of commercial scanners. But when it comes to PEPT, it's a bit harder because I believe application areas of PEPT is more diverse compared to PET, so it's not as simple to make a list.

Comment: This is what industry (or trade) magazines are for (or one use of them). Every equipment maker for that industry will advertise in the magazine. So, if you want to know who makes semiconductor manufacturing equipment you go look at Semiconductor International. I don't know the relevant industry magazine for your area, but I guarantee that there is one.

Comment: Thanks @JonCuster